# Adding a description to the change list page in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I'm working on django admin and wanted to add a description in the change list page at the red mark as shown in the pic

[image]

this is my admin file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    change_form_template = 'change_form.html'

    add_form_template='add_form.html'

    list_display = ('first_name','last_name','email','is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('first_name','email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)

    search_fields = ('email','first_name','last_name','a1','a2','city','state','pincode')
    ordering = ('first_name',)

    add_fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            # To create a section with name 'Personal Information' with mentioned fields
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide',),  # To make char fields and text fields of a specific size
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','check',
                       'password1', 'password2',)}
        ),
        ('Permissions',{
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide', 'collapse'),
            'fields':( 'is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )
```

So what is supposed to be added in the admin file so that description can be added at the mentioned placed??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this first you have to add a line in the admin file :

```
change_list_template='change_list_form.html'
```

So your admin file will look like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    change_list_template='change_list_form.html'

    change_form_template = 'change_form.html'

    add_form_template='add_form.html'

    list_display = ('first_name','last_name','email','is_staff', 'is_active',)
    list_filter = ('first_name','email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)

    search_fields = ('email','first_name','last_name','a1','a2','city','state','pincode')
    ordering = ('first_name',)

    add_fieldsets = (
        ('Personal Information', {
            # To create a section with name 'Personal Information' with mentioned fields
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide',),  # To make char fields and text fields of a specific size
            'fields': (('first_name','last_name'),'email','a1','a2','city','state','pincode','check',
                       'password1', 'password2',)}
        ),
        ('Permissions',{
            'description': "",
            'classes': ('wide', 'collapse'),
            'fields':( 'is_staff', 'is_active','date_joined')}),
    )
```

After that go to the templates folder and add a html file with name : `change_list_form.html`

Then in the file `change_list_form.html` add following code:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_list %}

{% block result_list %}
{% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}


<p>Add here what you want to add as description in change list page</p>


{% result_list cl %}
{% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.show_admin_actions %}{% admin_actions %}{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Remeber there will be different different effect if we use the range from h1 to h6 tags and for p tag

That's all you are supposed to do.